# Change Color of Programmatically Created Button when Pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm using a function to create multiple buttons for my game.

```
func createButton() {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x:15, y: 50, width: 200, height:100)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.view.addSubview(button)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonPressed:")), for: 
    .touchUpInside)
}
```

I call this function once for testing in viewDidLoad function, but I don't know what code I should put into my buttonPressed() function for the color of my button to change? I tried doing

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

but that didn't work. I also tried using UIButton and button instead of self, but both of those didn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: Update your question with your `buttonPressed` method and confirm that it is actually being called.

Comment: Your `buttonPressed` method can receive a parameter if it will have the following signature: `@objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton)`. Inside of that method you can access the button via `sender` parameter: `sender.backgroundColor = .blue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code isn't clean Swift 4 code. Here's how to do this:

- Create your button like you are, but change `Selector` to `#selector`:

  ```
  func createButton() {
      let button = UIButton()
      button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
      button.frame = CGRect(x:15, y: 50, width: 200, height:100)
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      self.view.addSubview(button)
      button.addTarget(self, action: #selector((buttonPressed)), for: .touchUpInside)
  }
  ```
- Use the `sender` that is automatically added:

  ```
  @objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
      sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
  }
  ```

Additionally may I offer a few suggestions?

- Check the background color *before* changing it. No sense in needlessly changing a button that is already blue.
- Since you aren't setting the title to your button, set the `tag` property (you can even add this as a parameter to `createButton`). This way you can know *which* button was tapped.

Comment: If I use `#selector` instead of `Selector`, I get an error saying, "Argument of #selector does not refer to an @objc method, property, or initializer. Do you know why this error is coming up? Also, whenever I click the button when testing, it leads to me to AppDelegate.swift file and gives me an error saying "Thread1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: Yeah, I forgot something in my answer - put `@objc` in front of your function. I'll edit my answer to correct this. I don't think that will fix your SIGABRT though. That's part of a much longer dump that should point you in the right direction. Regards to my button creation code, I just copied your code and changed the selector syntax. Maybe there's something going on there?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the button an instance property.

```
let changingButton = UIButton()

func createButton() {
    changingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    changingButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func buttonPressed() {
    changingButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
}
```